# Axios-mock-adapter giving Promise { _x: 0, _y: 0, _z: null, _A: null } when mocking the axios in react-native

Tags: react-native, axios, jestjs, axios-mock-adapter

I want to mock the Axios API in react-native and use `axios-mock-adapter` to mock the API. Below is the code.

```
const axiosMock = new MockAdapter(axios);
console.log("axiosMock ==>", axiosMock);
```

But when I run the test the `axiosMock` gives me a promise and I cannot mock the API

```
console.log
    axiosMock ==> Promise { _x: 0, _y: 0, _z: null, _A: null }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72106739/795683

Comment: @SainPradeep that post is for react.  For react mocking is working perfectly. But for react-native I am getting this error

Comment: Please check this example with react native https://github.com/shujathkhan/catalist